# Symfony 5 - Clear cache contract command

Tags: php, caching, command, symfony5

```php
use Symfony\Contracts\Cache\ItemInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;

$cache = new FilesystemAdapter();

$value = $cache->get('my_cache_key', function (ItemInterface $item) {
    $item->expiresAfter(3600);

    // ... do some HTTP request or heavy computations
    $computedValue = 'foobar';

    return $computedValue;
});
```

I use **Symfony** 5.4 and the [cache contracts](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html#cache-contracts) on an application and some cache expirations are quite long. My problem is that some values need to be changed and to do it properly, I would need to be able to purge the cache with a command line on my production server to be sure to have correct data.
I can make a custom command ex: `php bin/console app:cache:custom-clear` that invalidates some tags but I'm surprised I don't have a native command to do this cache purge operation globally.

It may be that it's simple and I didn't understand anything but I don't see much in the doc on this point.
If anyone has a lead, I'm interested.

Comment: There is a way to [clear an entire pool](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/cache.html#clearing-the-cache), but you are looking for a way to wipe a specific tag, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can call 'cache:pool:clear cache.app' command in a controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class CacheClearController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/cache/clear', name: 'app_cache_clear')]
    public function cacheClear(KernelInterface $kernel): Response
    {
        $env = $kernel->getEnvironment();
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);
        $input = new ArrayInput([
            'command'   => 'cache:pool:clear',
            'pools'     => ['cache.app'],
            '--env'     => $env,
        ]);
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);
        $content = $output->fetch();

        return new response($content);
    }
}
```